# Automatic update to 3.1.0 beta (2014-03-28 r65330) on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: r, cran

Today I was surprised to see that my work machine (Ubuntu 12.04 64bit) got updated to 3.1.0 beta (2014-03-28 r65330). My apt sources include `http://cran.at.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu precise`

Why did that happen? R 3.1 is not even released? Is it a CRAN bug?

Edit - re-opened here https://superuser.com/questions/739341/automatic-update-to-3-1-0-beta-2014-03-28-r65330-on-ubuntu-12-04